# MongoDB installation on Windows

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and trying to install MongoDB on Windows 8.1.
After I finished the `.msi` installtion and prompt `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe -dbpath E:\MongoDB\data\db`on `CMD` command, where the folder `E:\MongoDB\data\db` has already been created manually.
After I input that command on `CMD`, it seems that the program stops at `[thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017` and does nothing for a long time.

[image]

So anyone knows what's wrong and how to fix it?Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in this [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/?_ga=1.82566930.525730850.1428016333), the waiting for connections on port 27017 means that mongoDB is running succesfuly(server instance).
You will need to connect to MongoDB through mongo.exe shell using another CMD instance (client instance).

The waiting message in first console would change to connection accepted, and you can start working on your client side.